# How to prevent the shape of dot from changing when I change TextView number text?

Tags: android, textview

Let's just put some codes and pictures here.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/addTransactionFakeEditAmountText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="3."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="44dp" />
```

The result of this code is as follows:

[image]

Another code is here:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/addTransactionFakeEditAmountText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="3.3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="44dp" />
```

And the result of this code is as follows:

[image]

See? The shape of **dot** change. How can I do to prevent this shape from changing?

Comment: What font is this? To me it looks like it has enabled ligatures so you'd have to look into disabling that.

Comment: @Pawel I use "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" theme. Could you tell me how to disable it? Thanks!

Comment: I add `android:fontFeatureSettings="liga 0"` to the TextView. But it is still the same... not work.

Comment: This doesn't look like androids default "Roboto" font, is this emulator or phone? It's possible that your apps font is being overridden by system setting so it might be very tricky to alter how it behaves.

Comment: @Pawel Hi, thanks for your comment. These are all screenshots from my phone. Maybe I should set the font family or something to the TextView.

Comment: @Pawel Hi. I change this TextView font-family to "sans-serif" or "sans-serif-light". But it still doesn't work...

Comment: It would help if you could produce a small sample project the replicates this problem.

Comment: @Cheticamp OK, I'm going to make a small demo now.

Comment: @Cheticamp Hi, I create a demo project here: https://github.com/msl12/TextViewDemo

Comment: I ran your demo project and the decimal points are both round in a Nexus 6 API 31 emulator. Could be your device or locale? I am using the US locale.

Comment: @Cheticamp After setting another font series in my mobile phone, the shape of the points are round now. As you said, it is probably just the font setting problem of my device.

Comment: That makes the most sense.